# how to set the selected value for select , without java script ? html

Tags: html, google-chrome

is it possible to let the html search the list , i.e:

```
<select value="5">
     <option value="4"> bla bla bla </option>
     <option value="22"> bla bla bla </option>
     <option value="25"> bla bla bla </option>
</select>
```

I wan't to do that, because I have a long list options, and I should print it multiple times, each time with different value.

so i don't want each time,
 to look for the option with the suitable value , and add the `selected` attribute !

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You use the attribute `selected` like:

```html
<select value="5">
     <option value="4"> bla bla bla </option>
     <option value="22"> bla bla bla </option>
     <option value="25" selected> bla bla bla </option>
</select>
```

**Attributes**

**selected**

> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is
>   initially selected. If the  element is the descendant of
>   a element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single
>    of this  element may have the selected attribute.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't want to use the selected attribute , because I print the options multiple times and each time with different value, so I don't want to look for the option each time to add the selected attribute !

Comment: Then you have to use javascript for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add selected to the tag

```html
<select value="5">
     <option value="4"> bla bla bla </option>
     <option value="22" selected> bla bla bla </option>
     <option value="25"> bla bla bla </option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't want to use the selected attribute , because I print the options multiple times and each time with different value, so I don't want to look for the option each time to add the selected attribute !

Comment: Your question isn't very clear then, How do you create the list ? which opption do you want selected ? Bit more info needed

Comment: I have all the list options in a string $options var. so every time I want to print the list, I want to print <select value='x'> $options </select>

Comment: So it's php providing the options, Can you set selected there before it's output, Still not clear on what you're selecting, How is it being decided which one is selected

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) attribute:

```
<option selected ... > ... </option>
```

Quoted from the linked article above:

> **selected**
>
> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is initially selected. If the `<option>` element is the descendant of a `<select>` element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single `<option>` of this `<select>` element may have the selected attribute.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't want to use the selected attribute , because I print the options multiple times and each time with different value, so I don't want to look for the option each time to add the selected attribute !

Comment: @david this is what JavaScript is for. Otherwise: use some server-side validation and set the `selected` attribute there before the element is rendered on the page.